# Multi-dimensional/Nested DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested

I would like to store some multidimensional/nested data in a pandas dataframe or panel such that I would like to be able to return for example:

1. All the times for Runner A, Race A
2. All the times(and names) for Race A for a certain year say 2015
3. Split 2 Time for Race A 2015 for all runners

Example data would look something like this, note that not all runners will have data for all years or all races. I have a fair amount of data in the Runner Profile which I'd prefer not to store on every line.

In addition I have another level of data for certain races. So for Race A/2015 for example I would like to have another level of data for split times, average paces etc.

Could anyone suggest a good way to do this with Pandas or any other way?

```
Name     | Gender | Age
Runner A | Male   | 35
    Race A
        Year | Time     
        2015 | 2:35:09  
            Split 1 Distance | Split 1 Time | Split 1 Pace | etc...
        2014 | 2:47:34
        2013 | 2:50:12
    Race B
        Year | Time
        2013 | 1:32:07

Runner B | Male | 29
    Race A
        Year | Time
        2015 | 3:05:56
            Split 1 Distance | Split 1 Time | Split 1 Pace | etc...

Runner C | Female | 32
    Race B
        Year | Time
        1998 | 1:29:43
```

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742085/multi-dimensional-nested-dataframe-dataset-panel-in-pandas)?

Comment: @IanS The previous question was answered satisfactorily by jezrael, however it was not a truly nested dataframe. I have around 30 sub-values(Splits etc) per race for some races. I am looking for a way to store them in such a way that the columns are not necessary when I don't have that data.