# pandas incompatible shape for complex type column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I add a complex type (i.e. numpy array) as a column to a pandas Data Frame?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':['bar', 'baz'], 'bar':[1,2]})
display(df)

my_array = np.array([[[0.61209572, 0.616934  , 0.94374808, 0.6818203 ],
        [0.4236548 , 0.64589411, 0.43758721, 0.891773  ]],

       [[0.52184832, 0.41466194, 0.26455561, 0.77423369],
        [0.5488135 , 0.71518937, 0.60276338, 0.54488318]]])

print(my_array)
print(df.shape)
print(my_array.shape)

df['complex_type'] = my_array
```

Fails with:

```
AssertionError: Shape of new values must be compatible with manager shape
```

My version of pandas is: 1.0.0

### edit

A more complex example:

```
#%%timeit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
n_points = 50
d_dimensions = 4
k_neighbours = 3

X = rng.random_sample((n_points, d_dimensions))

df = pd.DataFrame(X)
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)
df.columns = ['id_str', 'lat_1', 'long_1', 'lat_2', 'long_2']
df.id_str = df.id_str.astype(object)

tree = cKDTree(df[['lat_1', 'long_1', 'lat_2', 'long_2']])
dist,ind=tree.query(X, k=k_neighbours,n_jobs=-1)


df = df.join(pd.DataFrame({'complex_type' : [arr for arr in X[ind]]}))
#df['complex_type'] = list(X[ind])    
df.head()
```

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Basically just one column added - but as an array. Like when reading a JSON dict I want to keep the list as a nested object inside the column

Comment: You may find this SO helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806414/storing-multidimensional-arrays-in-pandas-dataframe-columns

Comment: The dataframe has two rows, so a column (series) will have shape (2,).  But your array has shape (2,2,4).  Conceivably you could make the new column `object` dtype, and put a (2,4) array in each element.

Comment: on the first one, `join` aligns on index while on the second, the direct `list/array assignment` checks on length before initiating the assignment. As your error, it is clear that `len(list(X[ind_out]))` is not equal `df.shape[0]`. The creating dataframe and join works, but you should verify that the data got assigned to proper row as you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [29]: df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':['bar', 'baz'], 'bar':[1,2]}) 
    ...: display(df) 
    ...:  
    ...: my_array = np.array([[[0.61209572, 0.616934  , 0.94374808, 0.6818203 ], 
    ...:         [0.4236548 , 0.64589411, 0.43758721, 0.891773  ]], 
    ...:  
    ...:        [[0.52184832, 0.41466194, 0.26455561, 0.77423369], 
    ...:         [0.5488135 , 0.71518937, 0.60276338, 0.54488318]]]) 
    ...:                                                                                       
   foo  bar
0  bar    1
1  baz    2
In [30]: my_array.shape                                                                        
Out[30]: (2, 2, 4)
```

Assigning a list of two (2,4) arrays works:

```
In [31]: df['new'] = list(my_array)                                                            
In [32]: df                                                                                    
Out[32]: 
   foo  bar                                                new
0  bar    1  [[0.61209572, 0.616934, 0.94374808, 0.6818203]...
1  baz    2  [[0.52184832, 0.41466194, 0.26455561, 0.774233...

In [33]: df.info()                                                                             
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
foo    2 non-null object
bar    2 non-null int64
new    2 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
```

But note that you do not get a (2,2,4) array back from pandas; you get (2,) array with array elements.

```
In [34]: df['new'].to_numpy()                                                                  
Out[34]: 
array([array([[0.61209572, 0.616934  , 0.94374808, 0.6818203 ],
       [0.4236548 , 0.64589411, 0.43758721, 0.891773  ]]),
       array([[0.52184832, 0.41466194, 0.26455561, 0.77423369],
       [0.5488135 , 0.71518937, 0.60276338, 0.54488318]])], dtype=object)
```

Also be careful about saving such a frame.  A `csv` file will be hard to reload.

Comment: Sure, but I currently have an Issue with this solution - not with yours when I use more data: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`.

Comment: I have created an updated and more complex example which describes the error.

Comment: Sorry, it works just great your solution. I have a typo in my minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you need to flatten your array then just join it to your dataframe.

we can use `ndarray.flatten` & `pd.join`

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.ndarray.flatten(my_array),columns=['complex_type']).join(df)

print(new_df)

 complex_type foo  bar
0   0.612096  bar  1.0
1   0.616934  baz  2.0
2   0.943748  NaN  NaN
3   0.681820  NaN  NaN
4   0.423655  NaN  NaN
5   0.645894  NaN  NaN
6   0.437587  NaN  NaN
7   0.891773  NaN  NaN
8   0.521848  NaN  NaN
9   0.414662  NaN  NaN
10  0.264556  NaN  NaN
11  0.774234  NaN  NaN
12  0.548813  NaN  NaN
13  0.715189  NaN  NaN
14  0.602763  NaN  NaN
15  0.544883  NaN  NaN
```

edit: update

if order is the same then you can just create a dataframe with a list comp and join it to your target dataframe along the index.

```
new_df = df.join(pd.DataFrame({'complex_type' : [arr for arr in my_array]}))

print(new_df)

   foo  bar                                       complex_type
0  bar    1  [[0.61209572, 0.616934, 0.94374808, 0.6818203]...
1  baz    2  [[0.52184832, 0.41466194, 0.26455561, 0.774233...
```

Comment: No, this is not what I want. I actually want: `pd.DataFrame({'foo':['bar', 'baz'], 'bar':[1,2], 'complex_type':[[[0.61209572, 0.616934  , 0.94374808, 0.6818203], [0.4236548 , 0.64589411, 0.43758721, 0.891773]], [[0.52184832, 0.41466194, 0.26455561, 0.77423369], [0.5488135 , 0.71518937, 0.60276338, 0.54488318]]]})`

Comment: Why is the native list supported, but not the NumPy array?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler my naive assumption would be because a numpy array is multi dimensional and lists are not.

Answer (score 0):

for the first one, make your own array of arrays of tuppels of what ever and df will accept it

```
a = [[12,12],[23,23]]
df["a"] = a
```

as for the second one your adding column of a different len from the existing data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':['bar', 'baz'], 'bar':[1,2]})
df["c"] = [1,2,3]
```

will rise the same error